# django-viewflow : No module named site

Tags: django-viewflow, viewflow

i'm trying to develop a function in my project using django-vieflow. I try to understand the whole flow using this tutorial [ViewFlow-HelloWorld](http://blog.viewflow.io/post/96062197573/viewflow-in-action-10-minutes-introduction)

But, when i try to makemigrations i got and error saying No module named site. What did i miss?

Answer (score 0):

You tried to follow three years old instruction.

Check the up to date tutorial on the viewflow documentation website - http://docs.viewflow.io/viewflow_quickstart.html

And the tutorial source code - https://github.com/viewflow/cookbook/tree/master/helloworld

Comment: thank you,, i've follow the latest tutorial of viewflow and the cookbook.. I have no error but i don't understand how the flow works,, i mean how the task started?